# Elementwise vector Multiplication in cublas

Tags: cuda, cublas, elementwise-operations

Is there elementwise multiplication in cublas?
I am trying to perform these Matlab operations

```
x .* s
x ./ s
```

I have on host implementation using for loop and another CUDA one, but I wonder if I missed cublas library function that can do it in an optimized way.

here is my CUDA kernel

```
__global__ void elementMul(double *A, double *B, double *C){
           int i = threadIdx.x;
           C[i] = A[i] * B[i];
       }
```

Comment: can I post my Cuda kernel as answers

Comment: No the question is closed. I very much doubt anyone wants to set or user your CUDA code. There are many tens of questions with answers containing optimal implements of element-wise operations on matrices and vectors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20481390/681865 for one example, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955924/cuda-function-application-elementwise-in-cuda for another

Comment: I am working on vectors and matrices concatenating now and didn't find any question regarding that and at the same time afraid to post a question